# Social logins are not working on in-app browser's (facebook,insta)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, next.js, google-oauth

We have our website built on react (^17.0.2) which uses next.js (^11.0.1) and we are running ads on few pages where we are having social media login such as google, facebook.
So when trying to do facebook/google - login/signup from facebook, instagram in-app browsers google/fb login's are not working.

Facebook login seems to open a window and then closes

Google login gives a 403 error

**Libraries used:**

For facebook - `react-facebook-login`

For google - `auth2`

**Screenshots:**

[Facebook login is redirecting again to login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dok5y.png)

[Google login throwing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HpWU.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have the same problem and would like to know an answer/work around. I have a React app which uses a google sign-in button on the home page. I want users to access the website through my linktree url which is in my projects instagram page's bio.

After pressing the linktree url instagram opens an embedded browser which allows you to click a link which redirects you to the React website I made.

Now I have arrived at my React website and I'm ready to sign in from the instagram browser but when I do that I get the same error message "Error 403: disallowed useragent"

Comment: I met exact the same problem, seems FB.xxxx is not able to be called in in-app browser, which are well executed in external browser, like Chrome, firefox... after surveying so many related posts, maybe not using js sdk, but manually do the login process instead may be the answer (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow)

Comment: `Fb.login()` not working in facebook in-app browser. The only solution I found is to build manual login flow. That means not to using facebook sdk but facebook graph api.

Comment: It's 2023 and this is still a major issue, I am going to dig into this.